# VHDL: use WHEN - ELSE statement with variables

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

**The problem**
I'm writing a function in a package which converts some values for a testbench. I want to check the if the output exceeds a maximum value, if it does I want to set it to that maximum value. What I tired was the following:

```
  -- vec_in: 0...1023, returns -14...23.5 dB
  function conv_dac602_scale (
    vec_in : std_logic_vector)
    return real is
    variable val_in, dB : real := 0.0;
    constant lower : real := -14.0;
    constant upper : real := 23.5;
  begin  -- function conv_dac602_scale
    val_in := real(to_integer(unsigned(vec_in)));
    dB := (lower+(val_in*((upper-lower)/1024.0)));
    return dB when dB <= upper else upper;  -- this is the important line! (129)
  end function conv_dac602_scale;
```

When I try to compile this I got the following errors:

```
** Error: myfile.vhd(129): near "when": expecting ';'
** Error: myfile.vhd(260): VHDL Compiler exiting
```

I then tried assigning it to a variable r first:

```
  ...
    r := dB when dB <= upper else upper;  -- this is the important line! (129)
    return r;
  end function conv_dac602_scale;
```

Which did not change the outcome. I know that I can use a simple `if/else` clause instead, but my question is why I can't use the `when` clause.

**System**
Modelsim SE 10.0b, VHDL 2008

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `target <= signal when x` is a so called concurrent statement, which is designed for easy creation of signal assignments outside a process. You can use it within an architecture, but not inside a process. If and else are designed for sequential statements within a process. In your case, you'll have to use if/else.

Edit:
Seems this only holds true for Vhdl pre 2008. As fru1tbat pointet out, this is valid vhdl 2008 code and the problem is a not supported feature by the Modelsim compiler.

Comment: With VHDL-2008, concurrent assignments are allowed within sequential processes. The problem might be that ModelSim 10.0b doesn't support this construct (I don't have 10.0b handy, but 10.1 compiles it just fine).

Comment: Didn't know that. I have to look it up, sounds neat to use for some cases :)

Comment: @fru1tbat I'll have to try it with aldec.

Comment: I should clarify that it compiles **with** the adjustment you made where you assigned to a variable first. You still can't do "return ... when ... else".

Answer (score 0):

I would reconsider changing the way you call your return, as it looks like your syntax using `WHEN` is incorrect.

Clarify what you're trying to do with:

```
return dB when dB <= upper else upper;
```

That essentially is "return `dB` when `dB` is less than or equal to `upper`, else upper" where `upper` will not be returned due to the way you make the return statement. You may want to say: `... else return upper`

I would prefer an `if` statement in this case:

```
if ( dB <= upper) then
     return dB;
else
     return upper;
end if;
```

Comment: How is it doing nothing? It's essentially "return limit if value is greater than limit", which seems perfectly reasonable to me (aside from the problem with using it with "return" in the first place).

Comment: It won't return `upper` because of the way he's making the return statement.

Comment: Sorry, I interpreted your statement as questioning the idea, not the syntax. Conceptually, it's perfectly valid.

Comment: No worries. I will clarify that in my response. Thanks!